# How to install Lua modules (json, uuid, etc...) for wrk2

Tags: lua, wrk

I've installed wrk2 through homebrew on Mac OS. (https://github.com/giltene/wrk2/wiki/Installing-wrk2-on-Mac)

I am able to run the wrk2 command and simple load tests work fine. However I want to do more complex things for my request body that require json and uuid libraries.

In my terminal it seems I dont have lua installed

```
➜ lua
zsh: command not found: lua
➜ luarocks
zsh: command not found: luarocks
```

When I do import uuid or json module I see this error when running wrk

```
test.lua: test.lua:1: module 'json' not found:
    no field package.preload['json']
    no file './json.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/luajit-2.0.3/json.lua'
```

Whats the best way I can get these modules for wrk2?

Answer (score 2):

Just install with [brew](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install lua
brew install luarocks
```